# Remove Apple TestFlight beta entitlement before AppStore review?

Tags: ios8, app-store-connect, testflight

I'm currently running a beta test via Apple TestFlight for an iPhone app.
The latest build is ready for the AppStore. Do I need to remove the TestFlight entitlement from my build before submitting it for the App Store review?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NO need to remove your beta testflight build. You jsut need to select latest build and submit it for review. Please make sure you have added build with production certificate.

Comment: "Please make sure you have added build with production certificate" > You can't upload any other type of app to iTunes Connect AFAIK, so if the app (prerelease build) is already up on Apple/iTunes Connect TestFlight it should be ready for App Store submission